# asp.net siteMap menu using CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, sitemap, menubar

I am using asp.net sitemap with the in-built asp.net menu but this is very 'dull'. I want to apply CSS and jQuery to give it a better visual look and feel. I have read various articles based on http://conceptdevelopment.net/Fun/Superfish/ However, i really liked http://apycom.com/menus/1-dim-gray.html?affid=63CS-DR903

Is there any examples or tutorials similar to this which are FREE? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your advise... do you know examples which have a similar effect like http://apycom.com/menus/1-dim-gray.html?affid=63CS-DR903

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery Menu plugin with some hacks to integrate asp.net sitemap. I've post an example on how to do that at 
http://geekswithblogs.net/TiagoSalgado/archive/2011/05/11/jquery-menubar-and-web.sitemap.aspx

You may want to check it out and check if helps you.

Comment: it is frowned upon to link to your own blog without any further explanation. This is considered as spam. Please read the FAQ to check what constitutes a good answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've point to that blog post which contains more details about the user question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this (ancient?) code http://weblogs.asp.net/dannychen/archive/2005/12/19/433523.aspx which is a start at outputting the sitemap as a 'standard' unordered list rather than the tables the asp.net menu offers.  From this base there are many jquery/css solutions that exist.